# django issue starting server because SessionAuthenticationMiddleware

Tags: python, django

I have just been trying to get python 3.2.2 and django 1.6.5 to work when following this [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/). For some reason I keep running into this error and I have not been able to find the answer online as to why this is happening.

```
File "/home/salinn/.pyenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 28, in import_by_path
attr = getattr(module, class_name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SessionAuthenticationMiddleware'
```

I have tried changing the urls around a bit and tried playing with the settings middlewareclass, any pointers in the right direction would be awesome.

my settings.py file is

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '9xn60p#gnsg+es+xx@sx3f6b_f#stv!ik27myy+g9e3)mtgx)g'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: What do you have in `INSTALLED_APPS` and in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in your settings.py ?

Comment: Please search for `SessionAuthenticationMiddleware` in your `settings.py`, or better in all files of your project, and post all the fragments where it is mentioned.

Comment: @VasilyAlexeev I have `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',` in the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware` was added in Django 1.7, and you are using Django 1.6

Either upgrade to Django 1.7 or remove it from the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

You can check your Django version in the following way:

First, check which version of Django gets imported in a Python console:

```
import django
django.VERSION
```

Second, check the version of `django-admin.py` - this is the script which is used to generate Django projects etc. Run this command in your system shell:

```
django-admin.py --version
```

The versions should match. In case they don't you probably somehow have two separate Django installations (for example for Python 2 and Python 3).

As a sidenote, many external modules are still not compatible with Django 1.7, so if you want to build a real-world application, maybe it would be a better choice to stick to Django 1.6 for now. On the other hand, if you just want to learn vanilla Django, I think you should start with the latest version.

Comment: Should I just remove it then? That is strange considering it automatically gets added in when I initialize the project

Comment: Ok, are you sure you have Django 1.6? Do `import django; print(django.VERSION)` in a Python console.

Comment: yep, I got this back `Python 3.2.2 (default, Aug 27 2014, 10:31:54) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django; print(django.VERSION)
(1, 6, 5, 'final', 0)`

Comment: Ok, what you get if you run `django-admin.py --version`?

Comment: hmmm that is strange I get `NameError: name 'admin' is not defined
`

Comment: No, not in the Python console, run it in your system shell. `django-admin.py` is the script which you used to generate the project.

Comment: `django-admin.py --version 1.7b3` I am assuming this is the issue and needs to be down graded down to 1.6 something

Comment: Yes, that's the source of the problem. You are using Django 1.7's script to generate a project and then try to run it with Django 1.6. I think you should just reinstall Django.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60698/discussion-between-tall-paul-and-vasily-alexeev).